# iPhone with Outlook 2013 Shared Mailboxes

Tags: iphone, exchange

I set up shared mailboxes on Exchange server. The shared mailboxes work and receive mail on the desktop but while they show as mailboxes under the main one on my iPhone (Outlook 2013 app) which I tried first which didn't work, they do not receive mail either way.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It's not very clear what exactly the issue is… 'which I tried first' is most confusing, as it doesn't appear to relate to anything. Could you edit your post & provide more details?

Comment: Shared mailboxes have historically been a bit of a mess and not portable on any device OS except for Microsoft. If you don't get a good answer, consider editing this post using the edit tool under the tags to explain what desktop OS and client is working. My guess is Outlook 2013 app on iOS doesn't support shared mailboxes via Exchange.